# Dse Graph - Get all edges between two vertexes

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, datastax-enterprise, tinkerpop, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am using `DSE graph 5.X`.

Suppose I have two Vertex, Vertex A and Vertex B.

Dse documentation says about getting vertex and edges individually.

But what I am looking for is getting all vertexes of a particular `label` or all edges between two vertexes.

**How can I retrieve all edges between Vertex A and Vertex B in Java code?**

E.g `List<Edge> edges = graph.getEdges(fromVertex, toVertex);`

Thanks you ..!

Answer (score 3):

In general, the gremlin recipes page is good for stuff like this http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#between-vertices

If you know the vertex IDs then you can probably go with

```
g.V(ids).outE().where(inV().id().is(within(ids)))
```

Comment: what is `ids` here, id of a particular vertex or group of ids

Comment: g.V() is pretty flexible. Take a look http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource.html#V-java.lang.Object...-

Answer (score 2):

Hi Let me give you the dse graph query that will count's the No. of edges between two vertices , then you can execute or run the same query in java : -

```
g.V().hasLabel('users').has('userId','8e4b334a-388e-4623-91d6-fad7570e3129').outE('hasA').as('e').inV().hasLabel('mobileNo').select('e').count()
```

It finds for The vertex having label 'USERS' and in Particular to Vertex having some USER_ID , to Vertex connecting as 'MOBILE_NO' .

You can skip the user_id part query and can count between any two vertices of specific labels .